# What does "dig for diamonds" mean?

Tags: dialogue, curb-your-enthusiasm

In an episode of the 4th season of *Curb Your Enthusiasm* a black prostitute asks Larry if he wants to "dig for diamonds". Can somebody explain to me the meaning of this slang phrase? I can't find a definition online.The episode is called " the car pool lane" and it's the 6th episode of the 4th season.

Comment: In what context was it used?  Was the prostitute angry or happy?  Were they being intimate at the time?

Comment: Better fit on English Language.SE or Urban dictionary, no?

Comment: She was asking larry what sexual favors he wanted from her as a client.I'm just curious about the specific meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Diamonds is a term occasionally used for amphetamines (mdma or ecstasy).

https://www.erowid.org/psychoactives/slang/slang2.shtml

In this context it would mean a narcotic enhanced sexual encounter

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it is my opinion that body is like a mountain and the deep enjoyment or the real taste is the sexual intercourse which refers as diamond in the mountain.

Comment: close but not quite, this can be searched through google using the sexual context and doesn't really need to be discussed here, has no context relevant to this site